# How to disable lower horizontal menu bars in secondary and third monitors on Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have three monitors for my desktop, however the menu bar on the bottom is present in all of the three monitors, how can I disable them except in my main monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the taskbar on additional displays:

1. Right click on an empty space in the taskbar and select "properties".
2. Uncheck "Show taskbar on all displays"

Answer also found here: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3899-taskbar-hide-show-multiple-displays-windows-10-a.html